Migrate Apigility application to Laminas
I'm trying to migrate an existing application made with ZF3/Apigility to Laminas/ApiTools.
I already tried tutorials/guides supposed to get me through a proper migration, nothing ever worked for me, so now I'm trying to create a whole nes Laminas project, and push my existing code into it.
So I'm trying to get my first controller (a basic 'ping') to work.
I have my module, and the controller gets resolved to a factory string :

module/emma/config/module.config.php file :

    'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
            ...
            'emma\\V1\\Rpc\\Ping\\Controller' => \emma\V1\Rpc\Ping\PingControllerFactory::class,`
            ...
        ]
...


module/emma/src/V1/Rpc/Pinc/PingControllerFactory.php :

<?php
namespace emma\V1\Rpc\Ping;

use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Laminas\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory;

class PingControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        return new PingController();
    }
}


At some point, I break in vendor/laminas/laminas-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php getFactory function :
 private function getFactory(string $name): callable
    {
        $factory = $this->factories[$name] ?? null;

        $lazyLoaded = false;
        if (is_string($factory) && class_exists($factory)) {
            $factory    = new $factory();
            $lazyLoaded = true;
        }
...

The variable $factory is my config string (ie. '\emma\V1\Rpc\Ping\PingControllerFactory') which seems to be properly resolved, but the 'class_exists($factory)' returns false. It somehow calls the following :
vendor/laminas/laminas-zendframework-bridge/src/Autoloader.php::createPrependAutoloader(array $namespaces, ClassLoader $classLoader, ArrayObject $loaded)

But in this code, the $namespaces doesn't contain anything from my emma module. So I guess I'm missing something like maybe a configuration or anything to tell Laminas I actually want to load src/ classes.
But what I have :

composer.json :

...

    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Application\\": "module/Application/src/",
            "Emma\\": "module/emma/src/"
        }
    }
...


config/modules.config.php :

<?php

/**
 * List of enabled modules for this application.
 *
 * This should be an array of module namespaces used in the application.
 */
return [
    'Laminas\InputFilter',
    ...
    'Application',
    'Emma',
];

I tried to follow module activation cook books, but I cannot find anything about how to define an explicite controller factory class other than simply defining the class, which I'd say I'm doing already...

OK I'm stupid... It was a case mixup...
in composer.json under ["autoload"]["psr-4"] the namespace and not the module name is expected of course. My namespace is lowercase and module name starts with an uppercase E...
Now my class gets found !
